# Text box only shows half of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a text box that will only show half of the text inputted, unless the text box is a bigger size. Before I type, the cursor is half way showing, when I'm typing, it is normal, then after I type, it goes back to only half way showing. The text box is attached to Java Script that makes it so the inputted amount automatically turns into a dollar amount, would that affect it?

[image: Before I type]
[image: While typing]
[image: After Typing]

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[type=text].currenciesOnly").live('keydown', currenciesOnly)
                .live('blur', function () {
                    $(this).formatCurrency();
                });
        });


        // JavaScript I wrote to limit what types of input are allowed to be keyed into a textbox 
        var allowedSpecialCharKeyCodes = [46, 8, 37, 39, 35, 36, 9];
        var numberKeyCodes = [44, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105];
        var commaKeyCode = [188];
        var decimalKeyCode = [190, 110];

        function numbersOnly(event) {
            var legalKeyCode = (!event.shiftKey && !event.ctrlKey && !event.altKey) && (jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, allowedSpecialCharKeyCodes) >= 0 || jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, numberKeyCodes) >= 0);

            if (legalKeyCode === false) event.preventDefault();
        }

        function numbersAndCommasOnly(event) {
            var legalKeyCode = (!event.shiftKey && !event.ctrlKey && !event.altKey) && (jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, allowedSpecialCharKeyCodes) >= 0 || jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, numberKeyCodes) >= 0 || jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, commaKeyCode) >= 0);

            if (legalKeyCode === false) event.preventDefault();
        }

        function decimalsOnly(event) {
            var legalKeyCode = (!event.shiftKey && !event.ctrlKey && !event.altKey) && (jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, allowedSpecialCharKeyCodes) >= 0 || jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, numberKeyCodes) >= 0 || jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, commaKeyCode) >= 0 || jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, decimalKeyCode) >= 0);

            if (legalKeyCode === false) event.preventDefault();
        }

        function currenciesOnly(event) {
            var legalKeyCode = (!event.shiftKey && !event.ctrlKey && !event.altKey) && (jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, allowedSpecialCharKeyCodes) >= 0 || jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, numberKeyCodes) >= 0 || jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, commaKeyCode) >= 0 || jQuery.inArray(event.keyCode, decimalKeyCode) >= 0);

            // Allow for $
            if (!legalKeyCode && event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 52) legalKeyCode = true;

            if (legalKeyCode === false) event.preventDefault();
        }


        // jQuery formatCurrency plugin... see http://code.google.com/p/jquery-formatcurrency/
        (function ($) {
            $.formatCurrency = {};
            $.formatCurrency.regions = [];
            $.formatCurrency.regions[""] = {
                symbol: "$",
                positiveFormat: "%s%n",
                negativeFormat: "(%s%n)",
                decimalSymbol: ".",
                digitGroupSymbol: ",",
                groupDigits: true
            };
            $.fn.formatCurrency = function (destination, settings) {
                if (arguments.length == 1 && typeof destination !== "string") {
                    settings = destination;
                    destination = false;
                }
                var defaults = {
                    name: "formatCurrency",
                    colorize: false,
                    region: "",
                    global: true,
                    roundToDecimalPlace: 2,
                    eventOnDecimalsEntered: false
                };
                defaults = $.extend(defaults, $.formatCurrency.regions[""]);
                settings = $.extend(defaults, settings);
                if (settings.region.length > 0) {
                    settings = $.extend(settings, getRegionOrCulture(settings.region));
                }
                settings.regex = generateRegex(settings);
                return this.each(function () {
                    $this = $(this);
                    var num = "0";
                    num = $this[$this.is("input, select, textarea") ? "val" : "html"]();
                    if (num.search("\\(") >= 0) {
                        num = "-" + num;
                    }
                    if (num === "" || (num === "-" && settings.roundToDecimalPlace === -1)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (isNaN(num)) {
                        num = num.replace(settings.regex, "");
                        if (num === "" || (num === "-" && settings.roundToDecimalPlace === -1)) {
                            return;
                        }
                        if (settings.decimalSymbol != ".") {
                            num = num.replace(settings.decimalSymbol, ".");
                        }
                        if (isNaN(num)) {
                            num = "0";
                        }
                    }
                    var numParts = String(num).split(".");
                    var isPositive = (num == Math.abs(num));
                    var hasDecimals = (numParts.length > 1);
                    var decimals = (hasDecimals ? numParts[1].toString() : "0");
                    var originalDecimals = decimals;
                    num = Math.abs(numParts[0]);
                    num = isNaN(num) ? 0 : num;
                    if (settings.roundToDecimalPlace >= 0) {
                        decimals = parseFloat("1." + decimals);
                        decimals = decimals.toFixed(settings.roundToDecimalPlace);
                        if (decimals.substring(0, 1) == "2") {
                            num = Number(num) + 1;
                        }
                        decimals = decimals.substring(2);
                    }
                    num = String(num);
                    if (settings.groupDigits) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3) ;
                        i++) {
                            num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + settings.digitGroupSymbol + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
                        }
                    }
                    if ((hasDecimals && settings.roundToDecimalPlace == -1) || settings.roundToDecimalPlace > 0) {
                        num += settings.decimalSymbol + decimals;
                    }
                    var format = isPositive ? settings.positiveFormat : settings.negativeFormat;
                    var money = format.replace(/%s/g, settings.symbol);
                    money = money.replace(/%n/g, num);
                    var $destination = $([]);
                    if (!destination) {
                        $destination = $this;
                    } else {
                        $destination = $(destination);
                    }
                    $destination[$destination.is("input, select, textarea") ? "val" : "html"](money);
                    if (hasDecimals && settings.eventOnDecimalsEntered && originalDecimals.length > settings.roundToDecimalPlace) {
                        $destination.trigger("decimalsEntered", originalDecimals);
                    }
                    if (settings.colorize) {
                        $destination.css("color", isPositive ? "black" : "red");
                    }
                });
            };
            $.fn.toNumber = function (settings) {
                var defaults = $.extend({
                    name: "toNumber",
                    region: "",
                    global: true
                }, $.formatCurrency.regions[""]);
                settings = jQuery.extend(defaults, settings);
                if (settings.region.length > 0) {
                    settings = $.extend(settings, getRegionOrCulture(settings.region));
                }
                settings.regex = generateRegex(settings);
                return this.each(function () {
                    var method = $(this).is("input, select, textarea") ? "val" : "html";
                    $(this)[method]($(this)[method]().replace("(", "(-").replace(settings.regex, ""));
                });
            };
            $.fn.asNumber = function (settings) {
                var defaults = $.extend({
                    name: "asNumber",
                    region: "",
                    parse: true,
                    parseType: "Float",
                    global: true
                }, $.formatCurrency.regions[""]);
                settings = jQuery.extend(defaults, settings);
                if (settings.region.length > 0) {
                    settings = $.extend(settings, getRegionOrCulture(settings.region));
                }
                settings.regex = generateRegex(settings);
                settings.parseType = validateParseType(settings.parseType);
                var method = $(this).is("input, select, textarea") ? "val" : "html";
                var num = $(this)[method]();
                num = num ? num : "";
                num = num.replace("(", "(-");
                num = num.replace(settings.regex, "");
                if (!settings.parse) {
                    return num;
                }
                if (num.length === 0) {
                    num = "0";
                }
                if (settings.decimalSymbol != ".") {
                    num = num.replace(settings.decimalSymbol, ".");
                }
                return window["parse" + settings.parseType](num);
            };

            function getRegionOrCulture(region) {
                var regionInfo = $.formatCurrency.regions[region];
                if (regionInfo) {
                    return regionInfo;
                } else {
                    if (/(\w+)-(\w+)/g.test(region)) {
                        var culture = region.replace(/(\w+)-(\w+)/g, "$1");
                        return $.formatCurrency.regions[culture];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            function validateParseType(parseType) {
                switch (parseType.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "int":
                        return "Int";
                    case "float":
                        return "Float";
                    default:
                        throw "invalid parseType";
                }
            }

            function generateRegex(settings) {
                if (settings.symbol === "") {
                    return new RegExp("[^\\d" + settings.decimalSymbol + "-]", "g");
                } else {
                    var symbol = settings.symbol.replace("$", "\\$").replace(".", "\\.");
                    return new RegExp(symbol + "|[^\\d" + settings.decimalSymbol + "-]", "g");
                }
            }
        })(jQuery);
```

Textbox:

```
<input type="text" class="currenciesOnly" />
```

Code from free open source site

Comment: Post the source code please

Comment: Source code now posted @ByteHamster

Comment: There is no css that affects it @Eyal

Comment: @Domin8or That's odd because pasting the example you gave into jsfiddle seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/e8g09856/
I just changed the $.live functions to $.on to work with the new jQuery version.

Comment: I did notice that, would bootstrap.css affect it? @Eyal

Comment: @Domin8or Probably, yeah. That's what I meant by is there any CSS.

Comment: @Eyal sorry, my bad. I'm not too familiar with bootstrap, the bootstrap.css is from the Web Forms template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72528/discussion-between-domin8or-and-eyal).

Comment: It looks like you have a line-height set on that input which is too big for the size of the input field.

Answer (score 1):

With help from @Eyal and @LeoFarmer somewhere within bootstrap, the line-height was affecting it. So I set line-height to normal in the css for the textbox:

```
.currenciesOnly {
line-height: normal;
}
```